# When enqueuing javascript in wordpress, wp_enqueue_scripts vs wp_footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Is there any disadvantage to using wp_footer as the hook when enqueuing javascript files in a wordpress theme?  I have about 5 files that I want to be enqueued in the footer but setting the wp_enqueue_script property for footer to true isn't doing anything.

I have wp_footer() in my footer file and when I change the action to:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'extra_scripts');
```

the scripts load fine in the footer.  This is just for a demo and not anything more than just a front end display.  Is there anything wrong with doing it this way to load the scripts in the footer?

Comment: anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enque what you can in the footer.
To force this use:

```
// force all JS to the footer
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
```

This way you can use the default `wp_enqueue_scripts`
Do remember that some scritps need to be in the `<head>` like the [HTML5 script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/) of twentyeleven/twentyten